# How to know if a meeting is part of recurring series using office-js api without doing save drat

Tags: office-js, office365-apps

In my application I need to differentiate a recurring meeting vs a normal meeting, is there a way to get some this information in meeting compose form through Office-JS api without doing a save draft?

Comment: Got to know that it will be available in future release.